# How to use model in MVC flow

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp file that provides the login screen, upon submitting the form the control has to go to a servlet. Now, how can i save the values in the form to a model(Bean classs) and get them use in the controller.?
I am not using any frameworks like struts, spring, etc.

I used the following code but getting the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bean/LoginBean
```

**My code is:**

**index.jsp:**

```
     <form name="signin" method="post" action="LoginServlet">
                 <table>
                     <tr><td><font>USERNAME</font></td><td><input type="text" name="signin_uname" /></td></tr>
                     <tr><td><font>PASSWORD</font></td><td><input type="password" name="signin_pwd" /></td></tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="reset" value="RESET" /></td><td><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" /></td></tr>
                 </table>
            </form>
```

**LoginServlet.java**

```
   @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    System.out.println(session);
    try {
        LoginBean login=new LoginBean();
        login.setSignin_pwd("raviteja");
        login.setSignin_uname("raviteja");
        System.out.println(login.getSignin_uname());
        System.out.println(login.getSignin_pwd());
    } finally {

    }
    response.sendRedirect("");
}
```

**LoginBean.java**

```
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
String signin_uname,signin_pwd;
public LoginBean() {

}

public String getSignin_pwd() {
    return signin_pwd;
}

public void setSignin_pwd(String signin_pwd) {
    this.signin_pwd = signin_pwd;
}

public String getSignin_uname() {
    return signin_uname;
}

public void setSignin_uname(String signin_uname) {
    this.signin_uname = signin_uname;
}
```

}

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I recommend having a look at this link as it explains possible solutions to your problem. [3 ways to resolve NoClassDefFoundError in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Comment: What is package hierarchy of LoginBean?

Comment: did you compile your code? If yes, then was the class file in the place where you expected it to be? Is your output folder a part of your classpath?

Comment: Check import statement in your controller that is controller importing the bean.LoginBean or importing some other packages bean.

Answer (score 1):

1 Add Spring libraries to your project and map DispatherServlet in web.xml to process /LoginServlet

2 Create bean (same names for form and bean fields):

```
public class LoginData {
    private String signin_uname;
    private String signin_pwd;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

3 Create controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/LoginServlet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postLoginData(@ModelAttribute LoginData loginData) {

        // All data from form will be at your model attribute bean. It will also will 
        // be putted at request
        String userName = logigData.getSignin_uname();

        return "loginResult.jsp";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is bad requerements. Why they want it from you? This well known good practice. I sugest drop this project and go into better one where framework is allowed :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should run properly. You've a problem with the classpath. JVM isn't able to find the class `LoginBean` at runtime.

By the way what you want to output to the console? If you want to print the entered data user then correct your code with the following:

```
LoginBean login = new LoginBean(); 
String username = request.getParameter("signin_uname");
String password = request.getParameter("signin_pwd");
login.setSignin_uname(username);
login.setSignin_pwd(password);
```

But error shouldn't be if you correctly have created a project with your code.